# Area of the region and circles

Tags: geometry

What's the area of shaded region ? AB=BC=CD=DA=2 m.

[image]

Comment: Whats the length ob $BD$? Whats the formula for the area of circle/ square? Who much of a full circle is shown in the picture? - What did you try?

Answer (score 4):

Lettin $E$ be the intersection point of the two circles, consider a sector $BEA$.

Noting $\angle BAE={30}^{\circ}$ (this is because a triangle $AED$ is an equilateral triangle), we know the area of the sector $AEB$. Then, you'll know the area of a figure $BEFA$ where $F$ is the midpoint of $AD$.

Then, you'll know the are of a figure $BGE$ where $G$ is the midpoint of $BC$. Then?

Comment: Would be useful if you could add a figure too.

Comment: @Bernhard: I agree with you, but this is not so complicated. I hope that OP reads this with drawing figures.

Comment: I think what matlove said is enough !

Comment: Ok, you are OP, so no problem if you say so.